# apc.filters, How to include multiple directory

Tags: php, regex, apc

Can anyone help me with this?

I want set APC to cache ony two directory:

I was trayed something like this:

```
apc.cache_by_default = 0
apc.filters = "+/var/www/test/.*, +/var/www/test2/.*";
```

But this cashe ony "test" directory, not test2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **remove** spaces after each comma.

```
apc.filters = "+/var/www/test/.*,+/var/www/test2/.*";
```

You could simply use the following here.

```
apc.filters = "+/var/www/(test|test2)/.*";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your `apc.filters`:

```
apc.filters = "+/var/www/test/.*, +/var/www/test2/.*";
```

Try removing the empty space near the comma:

```
apc.filters = "+/var/www/test/.*,+/var/www/test2/.*";
```